# Extracting audio from mp4 has less bitrate

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, extract

I'm using `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -vn -sn output.m4a`
to extract audio from an mp4 file. However, when I open the mp4 in Spek, it shows 255kbps AAC and the extracted file is only 200kbps.
Also, the spectrogram isn't 1:1 identical, there are small differences.
Why is that so? Is it normal, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: As per Spek docs, it uses ffmpeg to read and decode files, so my best guess is that Spek uses an older version when ffmpeg did not discard initial samples from MDCT-codec streams. The ffmpeg output should be taken as accurate.

Answer (score 0):

According to DSP textbooks, shifting the frequency can have significant spectral effects, see "interpolation" and "decimation".  If at all possible make sure the sampling frequency and/or bit-rate is exactly the same, that will preserve as much of the audio as is possible.  Any other consideration must use various pre-filters to guarantee there is no spectral aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to demux the audio with something like mp4muxer or avidemux.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain *how*?